# First viewcontroller load steals memory it dosent need and sits on it forever

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I've got a uiviewcontroller with a scrollview in it and a few uiswitches (in a blank test project to examine this problem). When I first push it it takes a third of a meg of memory and I don't get that memory back when I unload it. Subsequent loads don't take any further memory but I am unhappy about this wasted half meg, as I want to add more viewcontrollers and this is wasted memory as they might be used once in the early stages of using the app and then not for the rest of the several hours the app might be used.

So whats going on, is the OS caching the viewcontroller (or its controls)? If I strip it down to just a viewcontroller it only hogs about 20k post unload. Add 5 uiswitches and properties and nothing changes but when I connect them up to their properties and it goes up to 300k and with a further 5 controls goes up to about 550k.

Im setting them to nil in viewDidUnload, and nilling and releasing them in dealloc, and dealloc is being called on the unload. But despite this I am not getting the memory back. They are declared as properties (not ivars, relying on automatic ivar creation) and authsynthesised, and I'm not directly accessing the ivars apart from in dealloc with release. Theres no reported memory leaks in analyse or instruments. Just this 'first time memory raid' after which the viewcontrollers appetite for my users ram seems saited.

In instruments none of my code is referred to on the stack trace (apart from main) and most of the loitering garbage seems to be from UIKit and similar.

As I say my only suspicion that I can think of is that ios is trying to be clever and imagining I am going to reuse this stuff sometime but its simply a total waste of memory (in my final app this will be taking at least 10 meg in total at this rate). If this is Apples choice is there a way to override it and force the memory to be returned to me?

Thanks in advance for any pointers this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS6, then `viewDidUnload` is not being called, you need to release your memory elsewhere.

Rather than bang your head and guess at what is holding on to the memory run your app in instruments using the allocations Instrument.

Now, take a snapshot of your memory before you show your view controller, and then take another snapshow with the view view controller loaded, then take another snapshot after you unload the controller.

YOu will now be able to see what objects still persist in memory between the snapshots, and this should help you see what objects are in memory.

Comment: thanks, have been trying to use allocations and heapshots but with strange results. For instance, my 2 biggest hogs at 47kb each are to sqlite (sqlite3MemMalloc) which I don't use or refer to in this view whatsoever. There IS a sqlite3 db in the main app but its opened on demand and my notes above refer to a time when its not been opened, verified by setting breakpoints and executing the same actions as when I take the heapshots.

Comment: Also there are 2000 objects remaining which is a lot to look through. Is it normal for ios to store viewcontroller data in a db for caching for instance? (BTW im writing for ios 4 not 6 for users with older phones)